# What is the Powershell equivalent for bash $*?

Tags: powershell

In other words how can I get the command line of the script itself?

So, I know about `$PSBoundParameters`, but it is not the same. I just want to get the string containing the passed in parameters as is.

How do I do it?

Comment: "I just want to get the string containing the passed in parameters as is." - `$*` doesn't do that.

Comment: Why do you want to do that, when you can take advantage of PowerShell's built-in parameter parsing?

Comment: @Bill_Stewart - I need to invoke powershell.exe with the same script with the same command line arguments plus a few additional ones.

Comment: Why? It would be helpful to more fully explain your use case.

Comment: My job spawns several parallel tasks using the `Invoke-Parallel` function from https://github.com/RamblingCookieMonster/PowerShell/blob/master/Invoke-Parallel.ps1. But then it has to spawn another batch of the similar tasks in parallel to the already running batch. For some reason I am unable to do it with `Invoke-Parallel`. Maybe nested Runspaces are not supported - I do not know the matter very well. Anyway, I workaround by spawning a full blown job using the same command line (almost).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$MyInvocation.Line
```

Read [about_Automatic_Variables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx):

> ```
> $MyInvocation
>    Contains an information about the current command, such as the name, 
>    parameters, parameter values, and information about how the command was
>    started, called, or "invoked," such as the name of the script that called
>    the current command. 
>
>    $MyInvocation is populated only for scripts, function, and script blocks.
> ```

Answer (score 3):

See `get-help about_Automatic_Variables`.

```
$Args
   Contains an array of the undeclared parameters and/or parameter
   values that are passed to a function, script, or script block.
   When you create a function, you can declare the parameters by using the
   param keyword or by adding a comma-separated list of parameters in
   parentheses after the function name.

   In an event action, the $Args variable contains objects that represent
   the event arguments of the event that is being processed. This variable
   is populated only within the Action block of an event registration
   command.  The value of this variable can also be found in the SourceArgs
   property of the PSEventArgs object (System.Management.Automation.PSEventArgs)
   that Get-Event returns.
```

*Example:*

test.ps1

```
param (
)

Write-Output "Args:"
$args
```

Output:

```
PS L:\test> .\test.ps1 foo bar, 'this is extra'
Args:
foo
bar
this is extra
```

Comment: My script has quite a few declared arguments.

Answer (score 0):

> just want to get the string containing the passed in parameters as is.

You're looking for a powershell equivalent of `"$@"`, not `$*`.

And the other answers in the thread are not equivalent. The best quick way I have found for this is:

`$args | join-string -sep ' '`

which can in turn be used for any string array you may have on hand, not just the `$args` array.