# What is powershell equivalent to "%*" in cmd?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, scripting

How do I write the following cmd script inside a powershell function:

```
@echo off
C:\bin\command.exe %*
```

Powershell Script:

```
function f{
    [CmdletBinding()] Param()
    # .. Code? ...
}
```

Comment: $MyInvocation.Line: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40753943/what-is-the-powershell-equivalent-for-bash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duplicate post provides a great reference but doesnt directly answer the question at hand.

1. Comparing Batch with PS:
   PShell provides a lot more Command-Line info because its object-based.
2. This equation can simplify things.

   ```
   $MyInvocation.line           =
   $MyInvocation.InvocationName +
   $MyInvocation.MyCommand      +
   [$MyInvocation.BoundParameters | $MyInvocation.UnboundArguments ] 


   $MyInvocation.line             entire string used to invoke script or 
                                   function.
    $MyInvocation.InvocationName   if present could be & (Call) or . (DotSource)
    $MyInvocation.MyCommand        Name of the script.
    $MyInvocation.BoundParameters  Variables in the param () parentheses.
    $MyInvocation.UnboundArguments Command-Line variables not in parentheses.
   ```

The %* would match up to either bound or unbound parameters. Since you have an empty param () you would use unbound.

```
function f{
[CmdletBinding()] Param()
    & C:\bin\command.exe "$(($MyInvocation).UnboundArguments)"
}
```

Sources

1. [How to get all arguments passed to function (vs. optional only $args)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/781472/how-to-get-all-arguments-passed-to-function-vs-optional-only-args/818118#818118)
2. PowerShell CommandLine Help about_automatic_variables

Answer (score 5):

If you want to define a `param` block and still capture all arguments you can define a parameter that uses the `ValueFromRemainingArguments` argument on the `Parameter` attribute.

```
function Test-Function {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [string] $FirstParameter,

        [Parameter(ValueFromRemainingArguments=$true)]
        [object[]] $RemainingArguments
    )
    end {
        $PSBoundParameters
    }
}

Test-Function first and then the rest go to remaining

# Key                Value
# ---                -----
# FirstParameter     first
# RemainingArguments {and, then, the, rest...}
```

Answer (score 3):

With a `Param()` definition you can't have unbound arguments (*edit:* unless you define a parameter to capture all unbound arguments as [Patrick Meinecke](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47803828/1630171) pointed out in his answer). All arguments passed to the function must have a definition in the `Param()` block, otherwise PowerShell will throw an `InvalidArgument` exception. The parameters are then listed in the dictionary `$MyInvocation.BoundParameters`.

Without a `Param()` definition all arguments to the function are listed in the automatic variable `$args` (and also in `$MyInvocation.UnboundArguments`).